# Position fixed Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

In Firefox when position is set to fixed, it behave like absolute. Is there any way to change that behavior, or just make my table elements to behave like in Chrome: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aduew9uo/)

js:

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky();
$( '#table tbody tr td' ).click(function() {
  $( "#table .ui.sticky" ).sticky('refresh');
});
```

html:

```
<table class="ui cellled striped table" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asddd</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdda</td>
            <td class="ui sticky">asdddd</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
            <td>raaarararar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In your fiddle, both Firefox and Chrome are making the header stack on top of each other.

Comment: Totally not true. In chrome they are well separated - strech result window